# Google Photos API Video byte stream url experation

Tags: google-photos-api

Would anyone know the duration/expiration time on the video byte stream url from the google photos api?

The one I am referring to is [Here](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/access-media-items#video-base-urls) where it talks about having `base-url=dv`

Comment: have same question too